# How do reduce the sourness of pasta cooked with peppers?

Tags: sauce, pasta, chili-peppers

I made pasta today using Parmesan Romano sauce and jalapenos and banana peppers from a can. The result was extremely tangy. Is this because jalapenos and banana peppers are sour by nature, or because some of the liquid in the cans was mixed as well? Would not using the liquid from the cans and only the slices reduce the sourness?

Comment: What kind of canned peppers ? stored in vinegar or in oil ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was vinegar.

Comment: If the peppers are jarred with vinegar, or water and citric acid -- both of which are common -- then you can't make them not sour.  Use fresh peppers instead.

Comment: Also what you **may** be tasting is the "can" flavor which can leach into the food. Its harmless but often detectible by some people. In my experience cooking for a longer time boils off that flavor, but that might ruin the taste. Me, I would use things like peppers bottled rather than canned.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the peppers. Jalapeño & Banana Peppers are usually canned as a pickle, so yes, it is sour.  You added some of the pickle liquid as well; I feel your dissatisfaction with the results. =-)

I love peppers (pickled or otherwise) in noodles. What I do to cut down on the sourness is drain the peppers of it's liquid and rinse with cold water once.  Then the results will be much more delicious.